# Possible ways to get to a point (on a prism)

Tags: permutations, 3d

[image]

I could find the answer by trying every possible way. But now i want to know if there is any sort of equation or formula i can use to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Use variables such as $x$ (down), $y$ (right), $z$ (forward) for one step in each direction.  Here the sequence would be $$x,y,y,z,z$$

Now find no of ways $N$ to rearrange this sequence. Here that would be
$$N = \dfrac{5!}{2!\cdot 2!} = 30$$

Now subtract the no. of cases $n$ when $x$ comes third in sequence **and z and y come left to it**, as Christian Blatter pointed out! That would be
$$n=2$$

Comment: That would make me more organized. Could you show me what you would do?

Comment: Why should i subtract when $x$ comes thirs in sequence?

Comment: Because there is no line in the middle of prism, lines are only on faces and edges. Also squirrel cant go through prism!

Comment: Now is it $30-4$?

Comment: @didgocks i have assumed that lines were drawn on the hidden faces too. i think that assumption is wrong

Comment: Alright. Still, thank you for your ideas